Jensen functional equation over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

$$f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\mapsto \mathbb{R}^{+}$$
$$2f(a+b)=f(2a)+f(2b)$$

So I am aware that the cauchy functional equation is linear when lower bounded. Hence I've tried reducing the Jensen fe to that. The only problem is that since zero is not in the domain I have no idea how to proceed. Any help or reference to a whole proof will be greatly appreciated.

The Jensen equation, as written here is equivalent to
$$f(\frac12(x+y))=\frac12(f(x)+f(y)),\quad x,y>0.\quad(☆)$$
Define $g\colon (-1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x):=f(x+1)$. Then, as can be seen easily, $g$ satisfies the Jensen equation (on $(-1,\infty))$ too. And so does $G:=g-g(0)$. Since $ G(0)=0$ this implies $G(\frac x2)=\frac12G(x)$. So (☆) for $ G$ reads as
$$G(x+y)=G(x)+G(y),$$ at least when $x,y>-\frac12$. But then there is an additive function  $a\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that  $G(x)=a(x)$ for all $x>-\frac12$. Thus $g(x)=a(x)+g(0)$ for $x>-\frac12$. So for $y>\frac12$ (and $x=y-1>-\frac12$) we get $$f(y)=f(x+1)=g(x)=a(x)+g(0)=a(y-1)+g(0)\\=a(y)-a(1)+g(0).$$
Since $f$ is bounded from  below on $(0,\infty)$ the additive function $a$  is also bounded from below on $(\frac12,\infty)$. So there is some real $\alpha$  such that $a(x)=\alpha x$ for all real $x$.
With $c:=g(0)-a(1)$  this implies $f(y)=\alpha x+c$ for $y>\frac12$. Let $0<y\leq\frac12$. Then we may choose some $z>1$ such that $\frac12(y+ z)>\frac12$. Then from the Jensen equation we get
$$\alpha\frac12(y+z)+c=\frac12f(y)+\frac12(\alpha z+c).$$
This implies $f(y)=\alpha y+ c$ also for $0<y\leq\frac12$.
Finally the condition $f(y)>0$ for $y>0$ implies  when using  $y$ close to $0$ that $c\geq0$  and using large $y$ that $\alpha\geq0$.
So the solutions are given by $y\mapsto \alpha y+c$ with $\alpha, c\geq0$, not both $=0$.
